# how to get position absolute div height in css

Tags: html, jquery, css

Parent `div` has two child `div`. First child `div` is position absolute div which contains `img` element.
`first-child div` is background with food image and `second div` is food description.

When screen size changes, `position absolute first-child div` and `second div` should be same height.
[image]

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}

.first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.second-child {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  /* want to set height with the same height of .first-child div */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <img src="food.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
    // food description here.
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to set second child `div`'s height as same height of first position absolute child `div`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason for not setting the img relative and the following element absolute rather than the other way round?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I updated my question and hope it will give you what I want. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't 100% what you're looking for, but it's the closest I could come up with using my own experience of using images as backgrounds for text.

I used floats rather than flexbox, setting a background image instead of img element and the height of the parent container to 100vh (in this case)

I then set the height of both children to 100%

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
      <div class="first-child">
      </div>
      <div class="second-child">// food 
description here.</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(/food.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.first-child {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.second-child {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  /* want to set height with the same 
height of .first-child div */
}
```

Hope that helps, if it absolutely must be flexbox you'll need a different solution.